# Testing if a number has a positive divisor of a specific form

Tags: prime-numbers, divisibility, primality-test

My problem is the following:

*Given a positive integer $n$, determine if $n$ has a divisor of the form $d=3+8k$ where $k$ is a non-negative integer.*

I'm aware there are fast algorithms for checking primality/compositeness such as the AKS or Miller-Rabin tests, could these be adapted to give an answer to this problem in roughly the same time? Effectively we are checking for compositeness within a more restricted space (checking if $n$ has a divisor in $\{3,11,19,...\}$ rather than $\{2,3,4,...\}$).

Comment: Any idea how big this integer might be?

Comment: I don't have a particular value in mind, but perhaps it's best to consider the case where it's large enough that simply iterating through all possible factors checking for divisibility is not feasible.

Comment: There are integer factorization algorithms more efficient than the brute force approach of iterating through all possible factors. (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization).

Comment: In this case the problem is not to factor the integer, but simply to test whether a factor of this form exists, similar to testing for compositeness (which can be done in polynomial time).

Comment: This is as hard as factoring the number unless $n$ itself is of the form $8k+3$. There is probably no efficient method to determine this.